# Can "text-overflow: ellipsis" be made to work on the "navbar-brand" text of a Bootstrap 3 navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the `.navbar-brand` text of a Bootstrap 3 navbar so that on devices like an iPhone the text is truncated rather than the navbar growing in vertical size.

I have two buttons as well:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-left">Back</button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >Branding text that can sometimes be too wide</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right">Logout</button>
</nav>
```

The `text-overflow: ellipsis` works (with `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` also set) if I hard-code the width of the `.navbar-brand` but I am looking for a way to accomplish this so that the maximum available space is used automatically.

**P.S.**

The CSS that works when added to the `.navbar-brand` when a width is hard coded:

```
.ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS too?

Answer (score 3):

Setting a `max-width` helped here with bootstrap 4.3.1:

```
.navbar-brand {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 70%;
    max-width: calc(100% - 4em);
}
```

The `calc`'s "4em" is because the mobile menu button needs that space.

Comment: in my case, i set `max-width: 60%;` and no write the `max-width: calc(100% - 4em);` code. It show good in my leptop and my android phone 5.2". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you set "navbar-brand" width: 100% the ellipsis property will still work and you will get the maximum available space.

Comment: Just tried that and the "navbar-brand" fills the full width and displaces the buttons to the line before and the line after.

Comment: @KeithC why not set the width of the buttons, to say like 5% each then give the branding 90% width?

Comment: max-width:100% worked with me too. that way i could keep the default widths of buttons

Comment: max-width: 100% on .navbar-brand doesn't work for me either. How do you do it without hard coded width?